# How do I set a color for the pressed state of the GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, android-listview, android-gridview

I am making an Android app and I use GridView with selector to handle click on an item of GridView.

Here you can take look how it looks.

[image]

But, I want it to look like this, but instead od this blue color to use my own color from above.

How I can make that?

[image]

Comment: I dont get yur question you want blue color for your girdview???

Comment: I want color from first picture, but as you can see on that picture, that is just color for background, and color isnt over image and text. Look at the second image, color is over image and text.

Answer (score 1):

use a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@color/button_disabled"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/button_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/button_selected"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/button_selected"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/button_transparent"/>
</selector>
```

save it as an xml file in your res/drawables folder

you can use View.setSelected() to enable it

Comment: Can you explain a litle bit more? Is there any tutorial about this?

Comment: I already use selector with states, and first screen is what I get.  as you can see on that picture, that is just color for background, and color isnt over image and text. Look at the second image, color is over image and text.

Comment: then in your click listener use v.setSelected(true);